# Doubly linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to create a doubly linked list..Here is my code but when i run it it is giving me this output:  `<__main__.DLList object at 0x10269d588>`. I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined special methods `__str__` or `__repr__`, so they default to the display you appear to dislike.  To get your own display, define such methods.

For example (in the body of `DLList`) add:

```
def __str__(self):
    result = []
    cur = self.head
    while cur is not None:
        result.append(repr(cur.data))
        cur = cur.next_node
    return ', '.join(result)
```

this uses no starting or ending markers, comma separation, and repr (rather than str) for each item -- of course, you can tweak each of these design choices (but beware: using str in lieu of repr can create very confusing displays, identical for lists that are actually quite different).

Comment: In addition to this, instead of `result.append(repr(cur.data))`, I would override `__str__` and `__repr__` methods for also `DLLNode` and then call `result.append(repr(cur))`